# How do you test PUT in functional tests?

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to test a PUT in a functional test in Play Framework 1.2.3.

I gone through the API of FunctionalTest and found these methods:

```
public static Response PUT(Object url, String contenttype, String body)

public static Response PUT(Request request, Object url, String contenttype, String body) {
```

My question is: How do you build the body value, to simulate an HTML Form submission?

Thnaks

Comment: What kind of request are you exactly trying to emulate?

Comment: I'm trying to emulate a html form submission. For example:
<html>
#{form @update()}
  <input value="${user.name}"/>
#{/form}
</html>

Comment: Why are you using PUT then? HTML forms support only GET and POST.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Is there any way with play framework to emulate PUT and DELET  out-of the box? For example, I recall that in RoR we use a form parameter to tell which http method to use and RoR do the correct routing for us. Is anything similar in Play Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried myself with a put but you can create a convenience method that initalize correctly a request for put and then use "request.params.put(key, value)" on it. Here is an example of put request initialization

```
public Request newPutRequest(String url) {
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.url = url;
    request.path = request.url;
    request.method = "PUT";
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Seb. My question is about how do I build the body param to send to the method. Maybe I don't need it?

Comment: For me you can send your params as form params with request.params.put

Comment: Thanks, seems now my problem is another one, how to emulate a PUT from a HTML form. See my comment to Tom.